# Trouble with canvas restore() javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am wanting to create a canvas scene that involves drawing lines. Literally, to give the appearance of solid lines being drawn from one x/y coordinate to anther x/y coordinate. My trouble seems to be with my use of save() and restore(). The way I understand it is, if I save() my canvas before I begin drawing, I can then call on restore() to reset my canvas back to that beginning state. In this way, I can begin my next line without a distorted canvas.

When the code below is run, the first line is drawn as intended. I then call restore() to allow me to work with a non-distorted canvas for the next line. As a result (so it seems) the second line is drawn as instructed. I again call on restore() to allow me to draw the third line from one specified set of coordinates to another. However, this third line is not starting at the coordinates given. It’s as if the canvas is still distorted from the previous line, but I can’t understand as to why. Can anyone shed some light on my dilemma? (Also, it there is an easier to way to create line drawings of this style, for the web, could you let me know?)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
c.save();

var a = 0;
function callVerticalTeal() {
    if(a < 200) { //draw line the length of 200px
        drawVerticalTeal();
        a++;
        setTimeout(callVerticalTeal, 0);
    }
setTimeout(callHorizontalRed, 1200);    
}

function drawVerticalTeal(){
    c.transform(1,0,0,1,0,1);
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(325, 200);
    c.strokeStyle = 'teal';
    c.lineCap = 'round';
    c.lineWidth = 10;   
    c.lineTo(325, 200); 
    c.stroke();

}
// Start the loop
setTimeout(callVerticalTeal, 0);

var b = 0;
function callHorizontalRed() {
    if(b < 200) { 
        drawHorizontalRed();
        b++;
        setTimeout(callHorizontalRed, 1000); 
    }
    c.restore();
    setTimeout(callHorizontalBlack, 1200);
}

function drawHorizontalRed(){       
    c.restore();
    c.transform(1,0,0,1,1,0);
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(325, 200);
    c.strokeStyle = 'brown';
    c.lineCap = 'round';
    c.lineWidth = 10;   
    c.lineTo(325, 200); 
    c.stroke();
}

var x = 0;

function callHorizontalBlack() {
    if(x < 200) { 
        draw();
        x++;
        setTimeout(call, 5000); 
    }
    setTimeout(callVerticalBlack, 1200);
}

function draw(){
    c.restore();
    c.transform(1,0,0,1,1,0);
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(325, 400); 
    c.strokeStyle = 'black';
    c.lineCap = 'round';
    c.lineWidth = 10;   
    c.lineTo(325, 400); 
    c.stroke();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You call context.save() only once. Typically context.save() is called first in any drawing method, and context.restore() is the last call. So it is an interceptor, if you want to call it so.

```
function paintSomething() {
    ctx.save();
    // now paint something
    ctx.restore(); // we now are clean again, because we have the previously saved state
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it does not seem to run properly. (I think I upvoted too soon). Running my code, as is, demonstrates a line being visually drawn from one set of coordinates to another. When I use your suggestion, the starting point of each line is correct, but only a dot appears at that starting point. The lines don't increment. Is there something more I am missing?

Comment: Seems like a clip issue. Can you type ctx.rect([startingX], [startingY], 10, 10); ctx.clip(); before drawing? If the line goes to bottom-right, of course.

Comment: Not sure what you were asking. But I couldn't get anything to go with that.